# To invoke java function from velocity template during onclick event

Tags: javascript, struts2, velocity

Web application uses struts2 and velocity

1)

The velocity file has a link and when the link is clicked i want java function to be called.

productform.vm

---

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="*************" id="acnt_link"> Add Acnt </a>
```

when the link from velocity file is clicked, i need java function to be called

### abc.java

```
public void printabc(){
syso("Java function called when link from velocity temp is clicked");
}
```

Please advise on how to do this

2)

i can invoke javascript function when link from velocity is clicked, but from javascript function how can i call the java function(for example abc.printabc())

Please advise.

Comment: What is the java function is doing? Why do you need to call it? Can you use DMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) which gives you methods from java as javascript function. Directly taken from their [Tutorial](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html):

```java
public class Remote {
    public String getData(int index) { ... }
}
```

And the correspondening html snippet:

```
<head>
<!-- other stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="[WEBAPP]/dwr/interface/Remote.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[WEBAPP]/dwr/engine.js"> </script>   
<script>
function myRemoteMethod() {
    Remote.getData(42, {
        callback: function(str) { 
            alert(str); 
    }});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myRemoteMethod()">Add Acnt</a>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Make sure you integrate the DWR into struts, they have also tutorials for that: [DWR Struts Tutorial](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/struts.html).

Another solution would be to call that java method via an ajax request:

```js
function myRemoteMethod() {
    $.get('/link/to/method/')
    .done(function (data) {
         alert('Return message of server was:' + data);
    });
}
```

This is a jQuery example, so make sure you have the library in the `<head>` of your html code. Call this method in the html code and you "call" the java method via ajax.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myRemoteMethod()">Add Acnt</a>
```

Comment: The second solution worked out for my requirement. Thank you.